# Reconstruction in a shader of an image rendered into several parts

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader

I am trying to reconstruct an image that has been rendered by column.
A counter cpt_x is increments in a loop from 0 to 4.
At each pass only one pixel out of 5 is displayed, every 5 pixels.

Thus, during the first pass, the pixels 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, etc. are displayed. => cpt_x = 0

then in the second pass, pixels 1, 6, 11, 16, 21, 26, etc. are displayed. => cpt_x = 1

in the third pass, pixels 2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, etc. are displayed. => cpt_x = 2

in the fourth pass, pixels 3, 8, 13, 18, 23, 28, etc. are displayed. => cpt_x = 3

in the fifth pass, pixels 4, 9, 14, 19, 24, 29 etc. => cpt_x = 4

The last step reconstructs the image, since all the pixels have been created.

The generation of images goes well, I can even reconstruct the final image after with an offset copy in a buffer texture using:

```
glCopyTexSubImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, cpt_x, 0, 1920, 1080);
```

As I now need different cpt_x values ​​for each pixel, I can't use this trick anymore.

I try to reconstruct the image in a fragment shader, but nothing is displayed.

The objective of this shader is to copy the pixels of the image to their locations, it will be called 5 times, at each generation of a 1/5 part of the final image, and copy the multiple pixels of cpt_x in the buffer of the final image.
The first pixels of the first line must be assembled as follows: 
1st pixel of image 1, 1st pixel of image 2, [...], 1st pixel of image 5, 2nd pixel of image 1, 2nd pixel of image 2, [...], 2nd pixel of image 5, etc.

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform int max_x; // equal to 4
uniform int cpt_x; // from 0 to 4
uniform sampler2D my_texture; // this texture contain only 1 column filled every 5 pixels

int coord_x = floor(gl_FragCoord.x / max_x);

vec2 pixel_size = 1.0 / vec2(textureSize(my_texture, 0));

vec4 res = texture(my_texture, vec2(coord_x + cpt_x * pixel_size.x, TexCoords.y));

if (texOneView.a != 0.0)
    FragColor = res;
```

As i said, nothing is displayed, I suspect the coord_x creation, since I think it's a problem of coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't in same space for all my variables. The code is simpler now:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

uniform vec2 max;
uniform vec2 cpt;
uniform sampler2D my_texture;

void main()
{
    vec2 uv = (gl_FragCoord.xy + cpt) / vec2(textureSize(my_texture, 0);
    FragColor = texture(my_texture, uv);
}
```